# Android - 'FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss' Crash

Tags: android, android-fragments, crashlytics

I'm working on Android Project -> 
Target SDK Version is 25
Build Tools Version is 25.0.2

Nowadays, I've started to get StateLoss Crash. Searched on Google, found many answers on Stackoverflow.

First of all, I cannot simulate this issue. Only seeing this issue on Crashlytics as

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

In stack trace, there is no enough information to understand. After some searches, I think issue is related with commiting fragments. My example commit code shown below. Note that, all commits are made inside `onPostResume()`

```
Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("LandingFragment");
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction tr = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if(f == null && !isFinishing() && !isDestroyed()){

            f = new LandingFragment();
            tr.replace(R.id.onboarding_view_fragment_container, f, "LandingFragment");
            tr.commit();
        }
```

In many articles, people say use `commitAllowingStateLoss()` but I know it's very dangerous to use. There is a great article about fragments which is http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html
but reading this doesn't solve my problem. I cannot simulate crash, I have no idea where causes crash... Any ideas to show a way or solution?

Sample stack trace shown below

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss (SourceFile:1538)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction (SourceFile:1556)
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal (SourceFile:696)
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit (SourceFile:662)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow (SourceFile:288)
android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow (View.java:13799)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:2860)
```

Thank you

Comment: this is a bug in the support library, see the issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=232418&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Sta

Comment: @gjsalot interesting...

Comment: I have the same issue and I'm not using FragmentTabHost, with 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0-beta02' and target Sdk 29 (min 16). Maybe it is something else.